# Plot cells between two positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i insert two points like x:0 y:0 and x:14 y:9 and change the background of all the cells between those points in a straight line? And keep it relative to the width and height of the table?

Example populating the table: So i want to connect the red block from x:0y:0 to x:14 y:9 in a straight line. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qy09q4jv/8/

```
var table = $('<table>');

$('body').append(table);

var mx = 15;
var my = 10;

for(y = 0; y < my; y++){
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    for(x = 0; x < mx; x++){
        var td = $('<td>');
        td.attr('id', 'cell-'+x+'-'+y);
        td.html("X:"+x + "Y:"+y);
        tr.append(td);
    }
    $(table).append(tr);
}
```

This is what i got at the moment:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>

        table td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #C8C8C8;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
        <ul>
        </ul>
        <script>

            var table = $('<table>');

            $('body').append(table);

            var mx = 20;
            var my = 20

            for(y = 0; y < my; y++){
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                for(x = 0; x < mx; x++){
                    var td = $('<td>');
                    td.attr('id', 'cell-'+x+'-'+y);
                    td.html("X:"+x + "Y:"+y);
                    tr.append(td);
                }
                $(table).append(tr);
            }

            var startX = 0;
            var startY = 0;

            var endX = 14;
            var endY = 9;

            $("#cell-"+startX+"-"+startY).css('background-color', 'red');
            $("#cell-"+endX+"-"+endY).css('background-color', 'red');

            var distance = distance({x: startX, y: startY}, {x: endX, y: endY});

            line(startX, startY, endX, endY);

            function line(x0, y0, x1, y1) { //http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#JavaScript

                var dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0), sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
                var dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0), sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1; 
                var err = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2;

                while (true) {
                    $("#cell-"+x0+"-"+x0).css('background-color', 'red');
                    if (x0 === x1 && y0 === y1) break;
                    var e2 = err;
                    if (e2 > -dx) { err -= dy; x0 += sx; }
                    if (e2 < dy) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And i'm stuck again :(

Comment: Do you want to change the background of all the cells which contains the x,y coordinates between the two given points round result when necessary?

Comment: So i'm gonna try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: Yes I think you have to use Bresenham's algorithm. I post an answer with it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Bresenham's line alogrithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Try with this code or with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albciff/hqzL3608/1/)

```
        var a = [0,0];
        var b = [14,9];
         // coordinates between two points
        var coordinates = [];
        var deltax = b[0] - a[0];
        var deltay = b[1] - a[1];
        var y = a[1];
        var error = 0;
        var deltaError = Math.abs(deltay/deltax);
        // x axis
        for(var x = a[0]; x <= b[0]; x++){   
            coordinates.push([x,y]);
            error = error + deltaError;
            if(error >= 0.5){
                 y = y + 1
                 error = error - 1;
            }
        }          


        var containsCoordinate = (function (coordArray) {
            return function (x,y) {
                for (var i = 0; i < coordArray.length; i++) {   
                    if (coordArray[i][0] == x && coordArray[i][1] == y) {
                       return true;
                    }    
                }
                return false;
            }
        })(coordinates);


        var table = $('<table>');
        $('body').append(table);

        var mx = 15;
        var my = 10;

        for(y = 0; y < my; y++){
            var tr = $('<tr>');
            for(x = 0; x < mx; x++){
                var td = $('<td>');
                td.attr('id', 'cell-'+x+'-'+y);
                td.html("X:"+x + "Y:"+y);
                if(containsCoordinate(x,y)){
                    td.css("background-color","yellow");  
                }
                tr.append(td);
            }

            $(table).append(tr);
        }
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: This works. I only changes for(var x = a[0]; x < b[0]; x++){  To for(var x = a[0]; x <= b[0]; x++){

Comment: @D.Wethmar Ouch! yes, I miss this. Thanks for the correction :).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
function changeBG(xstart,xend, ystart, yend){
    for(var x=xstart;x<=xend;x++){
        for(var y=ystart;y<=yend;y++){
            $("#cell-"+x+"-"+y).css("background", "yellow");
        }
    }
}


/* example */
changeBG(3,7,0,0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qy09q4jv/5/

Not enough details in question to determine how the range works but hopefully this helps

**NOTE:** You might want to add additional checks like ensuring xstart is equal to or greater than xend and same with ystart and yend

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
var table = $('<table>');

            $('body').append(table);

            var mx = 15;
            var my = 10;

            for(y = 0; y < my; y++){
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                for(x = 0; x < mx; x++){
                    var td = $('<td>');
                    td.attr('id', 'cell-'+x+'-'+y);
                    td.html("X:"+x + "Y:"+y);
                    td.attr("data-x",x);
                    td.attr("data-y",y);
                    tr.append(td);
                }
                $(table).append(tr);
            }
insertPoints({x:5,y:2},{x:1,y:8});
function insertPoints(p1,p2) {
    $("table td").each(function(i,e){
        console.log(e);
        var x = parseInt($(e).data("x"));
        var y = parseInt($(e).data("y"));
        if ((x >= p1.x && y >= p1.y && y < p2.y) || (x <= p2.x && y > p1.y && y <= p2.y)){
            $(e).css("background-color","red");   
        }
    });   
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qy09q4jv/7/

Note that the check if a cell is between those value isn't perfect, but it should give you a hint in the right direction ;)